# Check what is updating my file in macos

Tags: macos

I have a file inside /etc/pf.conf that makes some packet filter and I'm changing this file to have another rule, but after one minute this file was updated by some automatic process in my macOS and my rule is ignored.

How can I find which process is doing this update ?

Comment: Just did a google search for that file, and came up with this other question.  Seems like you might need to use the `pfctl` command after editing the file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719133/how-set-pf-on-macos-mojave-rules-and-restrict-ip-access

Comment: Try running `sudo fs_usage -f filesys | grep 'pf\.conf'`, and see what it prints. The program name should be the rightmost field (which'll probably wrap around to the left, unless you make the Terminal window *really* wide).